# How to simplify this code to make the complexity low?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The code below has a large complexity because of lot if statements. How can I simplify this part of the code?

Will the code simplified when I change the latest else if to a else statement without conditions? And will it work on the same way?

```js
parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
  if (value) {
    const date = value.trim().split('-');
    if (date.length === 1 && isNumber(date[0])) {
      return {
        year: toInteger(date[0]),
        month: undefined as any,
        day: undefined as any
      };
    } else if (date.length === 2 && isNumber(date[0]) && isNumber(date[1])) {
      return {
        year: toInteger(date[1]),
        month: toInteger(date[0]),
        day: undefined as any
      };
    } else if (date.length === 3 && isNumber(date[0]) && isNumber(date[1]) && isNumber(date[2])) {
      return {
        year: toInteger(date[2]),
        month: toInteger(date[1]),
        day: toInteger(date[0])
      };
    }
  }
  return undefined as any;
}
```

Comment: Apply switch statement?

Comment: There are some tricky things you could do to make the code more DRY, but I really don't think your current version is bad at all. Unless you had even more numbers in `date` to parse, I think your current version is fine and as readable as it gets.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes I think the same, but I get an `The Cyclomatic Complexity of this function is 11 which is greater than 10 authorized` error on SonarQube, so I need to make it a little bit easier :)

Comment: Sure, if it's a cyclomatic complexity requirement, there are some tweaks you can make.

Comment: Which tweaks? @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code so simple in think, but it so long!!

if you want example, i have javascript vanilla code for do that:

```js
function parse (value) {
    var list = (value + "").trim().split("-").reverse();
    if (list != 0 && list.every(x => !isNaN(x))) {
        return {
            year: parseInt(list[0]),
            month: parseInt(list[1]) || undefined,
            day: parseInt(list[2]) || undefined,
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
// below for testing
[
    "08-11-2020",
    "11-2020",
    "2020",
    ""
].forEach(x => {console.log(x, parse(x))});
```

---

Unfortunately I don't have any experience implementing typescript code, but the above javascript code probably helps you out a bit. Actually I shorten the code because of advantages (disadvantages?) that javascript brings, maybe convert to typescript won't make much difference !!

---

additional typescript code:

[On typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg5gIwCIENgQMrAE4FcDGwUAvFAN4BQU1UIEK2A-AFxQB2uAtghNgNxUanAPZtgACxbsuPfoOoATFCCkduvAQF8BFAGa42hAJaioYBgGdoACgBuKADa4IrCziNs4ASiit4yNEwcAiJKGih7bCgHIzcSKDtHZygAaigAInSvADp3TmscizAY4Gt0gFos7OwIW14rAuzOFDBrAA8SAD4oDoAfXqhygEYc5taYGV4vAXCjXQSYt2yHCE8JKG6ABigAMh3o2OBs2t4Qdq6oAEJYmBQYawn1bHavV939xaOT7DOO4m6Ot1hm8wuEaDVgLhsGxyPIweE6AxWJ8ANqbAC6UH6UAMCggug8EAUABo4fDqCIxOJkYcUUNMdjcfjCSSyeSlCAaW4UQAmBkDJkEthE0nkqCaOES8IQqEwwUsqAoCyKtggLQUAD0GqgPAcwgA7lBdMIoug3B44BQUXD0psABzDIblHmbF3pUU0dJDJ0ut0e6jpX2bd02kPhdJsYQSC3pCjo7LG7AAURQ+HE53+5HwogswhWy2EcHaxLMlggLy8mmmQA)

```js
type NgbDateStruct = {
    year?: number;
    month?: number;
    day?: number;
};

function parse (value: string) : NgbDateStruct {
    var list = (value + "").trim().split("-").reverse().map(x => x || -1).map(Number);
    if (list.length > 0 && list.every(x => !isNaN(Number(x))) && list.every(x => x > -1)) {
        return {
            year: list[0] || undefined,
            month: list[1] || undefined,
            day: list[2] || undefined,
        }
    }
    return undefined as any;
}
// below for testing
[
    "08-11-2020",
    "11-2020",
    "2020",
    "",
    "nothing"
].forEach(x => {console.log(x, parse(x))});
```

Comment: The year needs to always be in the *last* position in the input string. Eg, given OP's current logic, he'd need `31-12-2000` to give `{
  "year": 2000,
  "month": 12,
  "day": 31
}`. So the logic to implement is a bit trickier than this.

Comment: Too bad for my haste, maybe I need to fix the solution to get the right result. Thanks for the review!

Comment: @HenryTrần your code is nice too, good to read and understand.

Comment: @Can javascript is an interesting language, i think just need to change a little bit of your code. for example, checking all elements with Array.every and using the logical operator OR (||). in addition also easy to understand, with just the used it, it easy to remember!!

Your code is already good. Just shorten it!!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a regular expression to match digits, possibly interspersed with `-`s:

```js
const getDateObj = value => {
  const match = value.match(/(^\d+)(?:-(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?)?$/);
  if (!match) return undefined;
  const [, first, second, third] = match.filter(group => group !== undefined).map(Number);
  if (third) {
    // All were matched
    return {
      year: third,
      month: second,
      day: first
    };
  } else if (second) {
    // Only first two were matched
    return {
      year: second,
      month: first
    }
  }
  return {
    year: first
  }
};

console.log(getDateObj('31-12-2000'));
console.log(getDateObj('12-2000'));
console.log(getDateObj('2000'));
console.log(getDateObj('incorrect'));
```

In TypeScript syntax:

```
type NgbDateStruct = {
    year: number;
    month?: number;
    day?: number;
};
const getDateObj = (value: string): NgbDateStruct | undefined => {
    const match = value.match(/(^\d+)(?:-(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?)?$/);
    if (!match) return undefined;
    const [, first, second, third] = match.filter(group => group !== undefined).map(Number);
    if (third) {
        // All were matched
        return {
            year: third,
            month: second,
            day: first,
        };
    }
    if (second) {
        // Only first two were matched
        return {
            year: second,
            month: first,
        };
    }
    return {
        year: first,
    };
};
```

Comment: I need to use it inside the `parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {` when I try to use your code, the parse function doesn't work the same as before.

Comment: It's just a function name change. Just change the `getDateObj` to `parse` if you need the `parse` name. You can press "Run code snippet" to see the code working.